# How to remove the gap between the dock and the screen edge in macOS 11+?

Tags: macos, big-sur, dock, monterey

This gap is annoying me so much that I immediately rolled back to 10.15 after trying out macOS 11. And if I don't find a way to get rid of it before end of support for Catalina, I'll have to install Windows instead of macOS on my macbook.

Is there a way to remove it? I already tried a bunch of dock replacements, all of them felt pretty awkward to use.

Comment: The dock isn't really meant to go to the screen edge. Mine only takes up about the middle third on a large screen.  Can't you just put more in it or change the zoom size till it reaches, or does it stop short whatever you do?

Comment: I use auto-hide and on the work machines which automatically reset i use the shortcut to hide the dock.

Comment: Do you mean the gap BELOW the Dock (when on the bottom of the screen)? TBH, I hadn't even noticed it was there, or different. Changing platforms is a bit extreme -- I'd be surprised if everything in Windows was entirely as you'd want it, either!   
I doubt there's any configurable options. I'd just ignore it.

Comment: Yes, the gap below the dock (in my case - to the right, cause I have it on the right edge of the screen). I tried to ignore it - I can't. I already use Windows (and Linux too) on my other computers, so it's not that extreme for me.

Comment: Classic form over function, apparently it is supposed to float like the latest IOS, but this is not a phone... Interesting that the menu bar was reduced in size to provide more screen real estate, then they make this change. Kinda contradictory. I have to agree that opting for Windows as the solution is a touch extreme!